# Django nested serialization is not serializing on read

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I know this issue is pretty popular but can't figure this out.

```
class SpaceTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SpaceType
        fields = ['id', 'company_id', 'label', 'value', 'active']

class SpaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Space
        # space_type = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        #     queryset=SpaceType.objects.all())
        space_type = SpaceTypeSerializer(read_only=True)
        fields = ['id', 'location_id', 'name', 'description',
                  'active', 'space_type', 'group_reservations_active', 'seats']
```

I'm getting just the id for the `space_type` field. I tried the commented out part and get the exact same result.

```
class Space(Model):
    location = ForeignKey(
        Location,
        on_delete=DO_NOTHING,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        related_name='spaces'
    )
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    description = TextField(null=True)
    active = BooleanField(default=True)
    space_type = ForeignKey(
        SpaceType,
        on_delete=DO_NOTHING,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='spaces'
    )
```

Here's my model. Not sure what else to try but I want my `space_type` to have the entire space type object serialized.

Here's my query:

```
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    space = Space.objects.select_related('space_type').get(pk=pk)
    serializer = SpaceSerializer(space)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Not sure if i need the `select_related` in there but putting it in for verification purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idk where you got putting the nested serializers in `Meta`, but it's clearly not like that, here's a working version

```
class SpaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    space_type = SpaceTypeSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Space
        fields = ['id', 'location_id', 'name', 'description',
                  'active', 'space_type', 'group_reservations_active', 'seats']
```

Comment: @AlxVallejo You may get the full picture by knowing that a `Serializer` is actually a field and it inherits from `Field` internally, so you can use it as a field, even though that sometimes you sometimes instantiate it `MySerlaizer(obj)` or even `MySerializer(data=x)`, but it's still a field, so you can use it as any other field with the same arguments like required, read_only, write_only, ...etc